# Different elasticsearch response when debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, elasticsearch, nest

Strange thing - when debugging my code (set breakpoint) and when simply run it I get different response from elasticsearch server.

I'm using NEST 6.0.2 library, elasticsearch server version is 6.2.2

Code:

```
var elasticClient = new ElasticClient(new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200")).EnableDebugMode().DisableDirectStreaming());

elasticClient.Index(new Artifact { ImageId = 1 }, i => i.Index("artifact"));
elasticClient.Index(new Artifact { ImageId = 2 }, i => i.Index("artifact"));

var response = elasticClient.DeleteByQuery<Artifact>(d => d
                            .Index("artifact")
                            .Query(q => q
                                .Match(m => m
                                    .Field(f => f.ImageId)
                                    .Query("1")
                                )));
var artifacts = elasticClient.Search<Artifact>(s => s.Index("artifact")).Documents;
Assert.AreEqual(1, artifacts.Count());
```

If I set breakpoint on DeleteByQuery method and F10 the response is

```
# Response:
{
  "took" : 14,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "total" : 1,
  "deleted" : 1,
  "batches" : 1,
  "version_conflicts" : 0,
  "noops" : 0,
  "retries" : {
    "bulk" : 0,
    "search" : 0
  },
  "throttled_millis" : 0,
  "requests_per_second" : -1.0,
  "throttled_until_millis" : 0,
  "failures" : [ ]
}
```

And assert is success.

But if I just run code assert failed, two artifacts found. Response is

```
# Response:
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "total" : 0,
  "deleted" : 0,
  "batches" : 0,
  "version_conflicts" : 0,
  "noops" : 0,
  "retries" : {
    "bulk" : 0,
    "search" : 0
  },
  "throttled_millis" : 0,
  "requests_per_second" : -1.0,
  "throttled_until_millis" : 0,
  "failures" : [ ]
}
```

Both requests same:

```
Valid NEST response built from a successful low level call on POST: /artifact/artifact/_delete_by_query?pretty=true&error_trace=true
# Request:
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "imageId": {
        "query": "1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It only happen to DeleteByQuery method, simple delete by Id works well.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't inadvertently waiting for an async request to complete as a side effect of debugging?

Comment: Dont think so, it simple one-thread app.

Comment: Well, seems like it only needed an elasticClient.Refresh() before delete and before search.

Comment: There's a refresh interval before indexed documents become available for search (and queries). When setting a breakpoint, more time elapses than the refresh interval so works as expected. When not setting break point, delete by query runs before the documents appear as resulta

Comment: Note that getting documents by id is real time, so a document can be fetched (with get) and deleted by id straight after indexing